# Fill android listview with a new string array

Tags: android, android-listview

I just fill `ListView` with a string array and then in `onClickListener()` of a button, I want to refill that list view with new String Array.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use ListActivity instead of ListView. See Example

//List Activity Class

```
  public class YourClass extends ListActivity 
    {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

      super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.alertresult);

       showInList();


    }

    public void showInList()
    {

     ArrayAdapter adapter=new yourAdapter();

     setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    }
```

//Sample XML Layout for **alertresult**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

You just need to change ListView id to @android:id/list and setListAdapter

Answer (score 0):

you can set new list to list view(`myListView`) and call `myListView.invalidateViews();`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ListView with ArrayAdapter, and ArrayAdapter constructor needs an array, or an arraylist as parameter:

```
public void ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resId, Object[] array);
```

Create ArrayAdapter with this constructor, and when you want to change the data, just change value of reference array, and invoke notifyDatasetChanged() method.

Answer (score 0):

delete the data from  adapter using `adapter.clear()` and fill the new data to the adapter and call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```